# jQuery join or extend to dynamic dictionaries to the same ID

Tags: jquery, dictionary, join, merge

- Let's say you have 2 dynamic dictionaries.
- Both dictionaries will always be the same length.
- And both dictionaries will always share a matching "ID".
- There are an unknown amount of entries in each dictionary.  (e.g. both could have 4 entries, or both could have 20 entries)

for instance:

```
var dict1 = {};
var dict2 = {};

dict1.id = "3";
dict1.val1 = "4";

dict2.id = "3";
dict2.val2 = "6";
```

How can you merge both into 1 "final" dictionary, where they are merged at the id?

```
var main = {};
main.id = "3";
main.val1 = "4";
main.val2 = "6";
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with jQuery, this is just normal JavaScript. The libraries that are used for dealing with data collections are underscore.js and and lodash.

Comment: They're called objects in JavaScript, not dictionaries (that's Python).

Comment: Look at the `Object.assign()` method.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171251/how-can-i-merge-properties-of-two-javascript-objects-dynamically

Comment: Actually, jQuery does have a method for this: `$.extend()`. The name is even in the title of your question, I'm surprised you didn't find it when you searched.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jQuery.extend( target [, object1 ] [, objectN ] )](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/):

> Merge the contents of two or more objects together into the first object.

```js
var dict1 = {};
var dict2 = {};

dict1.id = "3";
dict1.val1 = "4";

dict2.id = "3";
dict2.val2 = "6";

var main = $.extend(dict1, dict2);

console.log(main);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```